# Redirect from wizzard to new form odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

From wizard I create new lead, but redirect to lead form not working, any solution?

```py
return {
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'crm.lead',
        'res_id': last_id[0],
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'context': {},
}
```

Comment: put the full method code please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the call from the button is good then i'm going to take a guess here that the you didn't use decorator api.multi

```
@api.multi
def method_redict(self):
    return {
     ....
    }
```